# How to get stock recovery image for Bauhn Amid 972xs?

Tags: stock-android, tablet

I'm trying to port TWRP recovery for Bauhn Amid 972xs (Amlogic Meson6 g04 customer platform) just to get some more life out of the device. The device is running android 4.0.3, my problem is I cannot locate the recovery.img that I need for porting TWRP using kitchen. The device is rooted so I can read the contents of root. It is also using Android system recovery <3e>. Any help is appreciated!

CPU: Amlogic Meson6 g04 customer platform
Vendor: Amlogic
Family: Cortex-A9
ABI: armeabi-v7a
Revision: r3p0
Kernel: Linux version 3.0.8

Comment: So effectively your question is what command to execute/which partition to save to dump the installed recovery ROM into a file. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, if that's how I could get the stock recovery. I'm fairly new to linux so if you could point me on some guides on how to do it or briefly explain how it's done I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There is no "recovery.img" as a file, this is a partition. See these two articles: [Android partitions explained](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-partitions-explained.3657183/) and [Making Dump Files Out of Android Device Partitions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-making-dump-files-out-of-android-device-partitions.2450045/)

Comment: thanks for these, will check these out. I'll just update for any progress